# PreviewTouchUp vs. previewTouchDown

Tags: c#, pixelsense, touch-event

I have a UserControl in a Canvas.  If I use `PreviewTouchDown` like this:

```
actualNode.TextContainer.PreviewTouchDown += delegate(object o, TouchEventArgs args)
                { actualNode_PreviewTouchDown(o, args, actualNode, name); };
```

it fires. But if I use `PreviewTouchUp` instead it doesn't. But I need to use both for my ideas. The same is with "TouchUp" or "TouchDown".

Does someone know why that's happening?

Answer (score 1):

There can be different reasons for this behavior.

Is one of the parents of the canvas a `ScatterViewItem`? If appropriate the `ScatterViewItem` handles the events.

Do you use the `ManipulationEvents` in one of the parents? If you do this, you need to set `IsManipulationEnabled` to `true`.

Another hint, use the tool snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to find out what events are raised and who handles which one.

Comment: Yes, one of the parents is a ScatterViewItem (it is a realy nested UI). Do I need to set the IsManipulationEnabled=true there? And thanks for the hint with the tool, I will look at it.

Comment: No you don't need to set `IsManipulationEnabled` to true. You'll see with the tool, that the `ScatterViewItem` handles the event. Look at the following link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/surfaceappdevelopment/thread/17b69899-69cb-429c-8fa2-f6623c5a62c3 read the answer on question 'Why doesn’t a control on a ScatterViewItem control raise ContactUp events?'. There are all options you've got named.

Answer (score 0):

After setting `e.Handled = true;` in the called method the PreviewTouchUp event is rissen and its method called.

Comment: If you set `e.Handled = true` in the `PreviewTouchDown`/`TouchDown` of the child, I guess your `ScatterViewItem` is not move-/scale-/rotatable anymore. See the link posted in the comments above.

Comment: The UserControls don't need to be moveable..., they have their fix position and size. Only the canvas in which they embedded need to be moveable